# Youtube stutter on linux, works on windows

Tags: nvidia, video, youtube

Youtube videos stutter and aren't smooth in general, even if they don't drop any frames. On linux it drops more frames compared to windows 10, both using h264 videos since vp9 videos are even worse. It works with mpv, internet speed is good.

I have an aspire 8920 with nvidia drivers, hw accel on and tried it on ubuntu 18.04 gnome/xfce/kde and manjaro gnome/xfce with chrome/firefox and all have the same problem.

I'm not really sure what to do with this, really weird problem.

Comment: This is possibly to be an issue with your discrete GPU, the CPU is being used in the wrong circumstances rather than the dedicated GPU. You can force the use of either GPU by using `prime-select nvidia` to change to dedicated and `prime-select intel` to switch back. You'll need to restart after each change.

Comment: @Hugo My cpu doesn't have an integrated gpu.

Comment: are you sure? All Intel CPUs, except Xeons, come with integrated graphics

Comment: @Hugo No core 2 duo has integrated gpu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither Google Chrome, nor Firefox support hardware acceleration for video when used on a Linux operating system despite what their settings may imply. This results in poorer playback. They do support hardware acceleration under Windows.

References:

1. https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/10/hardware-acceleration-chrome-linux
2. http://disq.us/p/1wai2e0
3. http://disq.us/p/1wcbkhr
4. http://disq.us/p/1waleu7
5. http://disq.us/p/1wbysui
6. http://disq.us/p/1wcs530

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I'll try chromium with va-api patch, do you know any other way of getting a hw accel browser on linux?

Comment: Turns out it only works only with the free driver video-linux on nvidia, but the video is corrupted..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for 2 years. I noticed the frame drop when watching streaming on twich or youtube. I recently found a fix to my problem to use nvidia drm mode. 
First selecting performance mode in nvidia panel. Then open the file 
`sudo nano /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-kms.conf`
 Delete or comment the line 
`options nvidia-drm modeset=1`. 
After reboot you can see 
`[    5.384353] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  435.21` 
with dmesg command. And there are no more frame drop in video or games.